# Seller of iPhone included photos of IMEI, MEID, ICCID on public site

Tags: iphone, smartphone, imei

I was buying an iPhone from a well-known website. I did not notice this before buying otherwise I would not have bought it.

But after the item was shipped I noticed the seller had included a screenshot of the iPhone with MEID, SN, IMEI, ICCID showing. He also included a picture of the box, which shows EID, IMEI2, Serial No, IMEI/MEID. I am reading some blogs about what can be done with these numbers and it's a lot of scary stuff.

Like someone could commit a crime and frame me for it. Or someone could get a stolen phone with bad IMEI and give it my IMEI.  I am feeling nervous. Maybe I should return the phone and buy another. I am sure scammers browse this website hunting for these numbers. What can a scammer do with these numbers? What are the threats?

Comment: Hi Fred, how are you thinking that other people would get hold of this information ?  If this info was included in the box, then maybe someone could have tampered with your phone.

Comment: @RohitGupta the info was in the images on the website.